# Find general solution

Tags: recurrence-relations

I want to find the general solution for the following :
$$t(n)=t(\frac{n}{4})+\sqrt{n}+n^2+n^2log_{8}n $$ Note: $n=4^k$
$t(n)=t(4^k)=t_{k}$
$$t_{k}=t_{k-1}+2^k+16^k\cdot \frac{2}{3}k$$
$$\rho(x)=(x-1)(x-2)(x-16)^2$$
There is problem to find the coefficients, any advice? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hint: plug in $t_k = a \cdot 2^k + (b k + c) \cdot 16^k$,
$t_{k-1} = \dfrac{a}{2} \cdot 2^k + \dfrac{b k - b + c}{16} \cdot 16^k$ to the recurrence, and see what constants $a,b,c$ make this work.

Comment: that's what I got:
$$c_{2}9^k + c_{3}k9^k +c_{4}3^k = c_{2}9^{k-1}+c_{3}k9^{k-1}-c_{3}9^{k-1}+c_{4}3^{k-1}+k9^k + 3^k$$

what now?

Answer (score 1):

As you state, the change of variable $n = 4^k$ and $t(4^k) = t_k$ reduces the recurrence to:
$$
t_{k + 1} = t_k + 2 \cdot 2^k + 16 \cdot 16^k + \frac{32 k}{3} \cdot 16^k
$$
Define the generating function:
$$
T(z) = \sum_{k \ge 0} t_k z^k
$$
multiply the recurrence by $z^k$, sum over $k \ge 0$, and recognize a few sums,
like:
$$
\sum_{k \ge 0} k a^k z^k
  = z \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} z} \frac{1}{1 - a z}
  = \frac{a z}{(1 - a z)^2}
$$
to get:
$$
\frac{T(z) - t_0}{z}
  = T(z)
      + 2 \cdot \frac{1}{1 - 2 z}
      + 16 \cdot \frac{1}{1 - 16 z}
      + \frac{32}{3} \cdot \frac{16 z}{(1 - 16 z)^2}
$$
Solve as partial fractions:
$$
T(z)
  = \frac{32}{45} \cdot \frac{1}{(1 - 16 z)^2}
      - \frac{272}{675} \cdot \frac{1}{1 - 16 z}
      + 2 \cdot \frac{1}{1 - 2 z}
      + \frac{675 t_0 - 1558}{675} \cdot \frac{1}{1 - z}
$$
Now use the generalized binomial theorem:
$$
(1 + u)^{-m} 
  = \sum_{k \ge 0} \binom{-m}{n} u^k
  = \sum_{k \ge 0} (-1)^k \binom{k + m - 1}{m - 1} u^k
$$
in particular:
$$
\binom{-2}{k} = (-1)^k(k + 1)
$$
to finish this off:
\begin{align}
t_k
  &= \frac{32}{45} (k + 1) \cdot 16^k
       - \frac{272}{675} \cdot 16^k
       + 2 \cdot 2^k
       + \frac{675 t_0 - 1558}{675} \\
  &= \frac{32}{45} \cdot k \cdot 16^k 
       + \frac{208}{675} \cdot 16^k
       + 2 \cdot 2^k
       + \frac{675 t_0 - 1558}{675} \\
t(n)
  &= \frac{32}{45} n^2 \log_4 n
       - \frac{272}{675} n^2
       + 2 \sqrt{n}
       + \frac{675 t_0 - 1558}{675}
\end{align}

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but this is not the approach we learned in the class. its good for my knowledge but "on the paper" they want the way Robart wrote to me. I just dont know how to continue, I wrote him down the equation I have got. again, thanks.